# Using html for excel 2013 with Custom format for currency

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, excel-2013

I am exporting data from my site to excel, using HTML.

For currency, i am using the following class:

```
.DDD {
            mso-number-format: '\0022$\0022\#\,\#\#0\.00';
        }
```

When I open it in excel 2007-2010 the behavior is OK. (i see the number with the currency, but when i edit the cell, you can see it is a number - so you can use function like Sum() on it)
BUT when I open it in excel 2013 I can't use functions, and I see the cell value is "$10.00" (and not 10.00) - so it is NOT a number.

I'm using "$" just for this example, the actual currency is NIS ("₪")

Is there a way to make it work for all excels?

My relevant HTML was:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="DDD">
    <span>$</span>
    <span>1234.56</span>
  </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

Eventually I removed the span with the currency, and it works fine on all excels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please show the `HTML` to this `CSS`?

Because if I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">

<style>
.DDD {
 mso-number-format:"\0022₪\0022\#,\#\#0\.00";
}
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="DDD">1234.56</td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

then the Excel looks like:

[image]

in Excel 2016. This is a German Excel. So 1234,56 is a number.

I don't believe that Excel 2013 is as much different with this.

---

If the need is also to have the format in browser view, then you could have:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">

<style>
.DDD {
 mso-number-format: "\0022₪\0022#,##0.00";
 font-size: 2em;
}
.DDD::before {
 content: "₪";
}
.DDD .thousand::before {
 content: ",";
}
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="DDD">1<span class="thousand">234</span>.56</td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

But better approach will be, strictly separate view requirements from data export requirements. So to have different formats for view and data export. And in conclusion of all considerations, **not** to use HTML for data export but XML or better the needed format - Excel in this case - directly.

Comment: I will try adding the meta tag, not sure I have it... update tomorrow! thanks for your time.

Comment: I've removed the span with the currency so I will have html like your answer and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the supplements.  I am actually using c# MVC (cshtml file) so I am not rendering the other span, only if "import to excel", so that's enough for me ;)