# Formatting an Inline Spreadsheet Generated by ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, formatting, spreadsheet, inline

I'd like to format a column (as four-decimal currency) of a spreadsheet generated by ColdFusion, then serve it to the requestor as inline content. Here's the basic idea:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=FundHistory_Report.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
  <!-- HTML table data to display spreadhseet data -->
</cfcontent>
```

That's the file and content headed back to the browser, but I'd like to format the column before doing so.

This would normally be straightforward just using SpreadsheetFormatColumn() if the file actually existed somewhere (maybe it does!). My question is, how can I access this spreadsheet, make the formatting changes, then serve it to the requestor?

Comment: The cfcontent tag says you are returning a spreadsheet but the comments say HTML. Which is it? They are two different animals...

Comment: ColdFusion can use HTML to represent the columns and rows of a worksheet.

Comment: (Edit) So you are returning HTML. You'd need to modify the code generating the html table and use something like MS's CSS styles (ie `mso-number-format`) .  Also, you might want to switch to using a real spreadsheet, as modern versions of Excel now display a warning for HTML masquerading as a spreadsheet, due to extension hardening i.e. security reasons

Comment: @JRomeo Ageax is correct, you have an HTML document, not a spreadsheet workbook. You can look at this [question and answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36397486/923833) to get going on formatting the HTML document for excel viewing.

Comment: For the method you want to use, you don't format the column.  You format the contents of the table cells as you generate them using ColdFusion's `NumberFormat()` function.

Comment: If you intend to open the html in Excel, you may need to do both. As Excel my alter the display of the values, regardless. This another reason to use a real spreadsheet, instead of html - greater control.